# Query items from DynamoDB in AWS Glue script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue, dynamodb-queries

The following code scans a DDB table and creates a dynamic frame in PySpark:

```
dynamic_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
            connection_type="dynamodb",
            connection_options={
                "dynamodb.export": "ddb",
                "dynamodb.s3.bucket": self.ddb_s3_bucket,
                "dynamodb.s3.prefix": 'temporary/ddbexport/',
                "dynamodb.tableArn": <ddb_table_arn>,
                "dynamodb.unnestDDBJson": True,
            },
            transformation_ctx="dynamic_frame",
        )
```

The dynamic frame would contain all the records in the DDB. Does Glue offer a way to query items in DDB based on primary key and create a dynamic frame?

The boto3 library can be used to create a DDB client to query the items, however I am unsure how I can create a dynamic frame out of the response. Also, the `batch_get_items` would return only 100 records at a time

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared does not `Scan` a DynamoDB table, it exports it to S3 and reads the data from there.

Glue cannot Query data. You would need to use boto3 as you stated. You can convert a list to a dataframe easily:

```
data1 = query_response
columns = ["pk", "sk", "data1"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
```

As for `BatchGetItem` only returning 100 items, you don't want to use BatchGet you want to use `Query` where you can get all the data related to a partition key.